# Drawing a rectangle, giving the sides different layouts

Tags: tikz-pgf

given two coordinates (v1) and (v2) my goal is to draw a rectangle, that looks as follows:

1. One side is uniquely defined by (v1)--(v2).
2. The other side has a length of 1.
3. The line through (v1)--(v2) is black.
4. The line parallel to (v1)--(v2) is green.
5. The other sides are grey and doted.

Does anyone know how to do this? I tried computing the explicit corners of the rectangle, but this yields really nasty numbers.

With easy coordinates it's supposed to look like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (v1) at (-3, 0);
\coordinate (v2) at (3,0);
\coordinate (v3) at (3,1);
\coordinate (v4) at (-3,1);

\draw[fill, black] (v1) circle[radius=1pt];
\draw[fill, black] (v2) circle[radius=1pt];
\draw[fill, black] (v3) circle[radius=1pt];
\draw[fill, black] (v4) circle[radius=1pt];

\draw (v1)--(v2);
\draw [gray, dashed] (v2)--(v3);
\draw [green] (v3)--(v4);
\draw [gray, dashed] (v4)--(v1);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

But what do you do if you cannot simply compute (v3) and (v4), so if for example (v1)=(-5,3) and (v2)=(2,1).

Comment: Cancel the last line from your code. Then complete the code for a working program:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

This is very easy with Ti*k*Z `calc` library. Using it you can create a macro for the task. Something like the following example:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\myrectangle}[2]
{
  \coordinate (aux1) at ($(#1)!1cm!90:(#2)$);
  \coordinate (aux2) at ($(#2)!1cm!-90:(#1)$);
  \draw[gray, dashed] (#1) -- (aux1);
  \draw[gray, dashed] (#2) -- (aux2);
  \draw (#1) -- (#2);
  \draw[green] (aux1) -- (aux2);
  \foreach\i in {(#1),(#2),(aux1),(aux2)}
    \filldraw \i circle [radius=1pt];
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (v1) at (-3, 0);
\coordinate (v2) at (3,0);

\myrectangle{v1}{v2}
\myrectangle{2,3}{5,-1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]